# Craft 3 Redirect after login based on User field

Tags: redirect, login

i'd like to alter the after login redirect URL based on a User custom field, i encountered [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19189/redirecting-after-login-based-on-user-group) but looks like it's not applicable to Craft 3.

I could re-write the whole UsersController class on a custom plugin but maybe there's another way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use Freeform's [Element Connections](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/overview/element-connections.html#craft-users) to create a user registration form. In the form's [Return URL setting](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/overview/forms-composer.html#form-settings) it looks like there's some options to create some logic with {{ submission.id }}.